# cant combine two streams to display as one in GUI

Tags: java, arrays, filter, collections, stream

I am filtering out games and consoles but then I want to display them both in a GUI, only one of the streams will display at a time, both streams do what I want them to I just can't find out how to combine a collection of games and consoles

//both streams cycle through an array of Rentals that have the consoles, games, names, etc

//filters out the name of games

```
    filteredListRentals = (ArrayList<Rental>) listOfRentals.stream().
                    filter(n -> n instanceof Game)
                    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

//filters out the name of the consoles

```
    filteredListRentals = (ArrayList<Rental>) listOfRentals.stream().
                    filter(n -> n instanceof Console)
                    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

//sorts by the name of costumers, this works along with the stream being displayed

```
   Collections.sort(fileredListRentals, (n1, n2) ->
          n1.getNameOfRenter().compareTo(n2.nameOfRenter));
```

Comment: What are you trying to do here? Create a new list and add both (list of `Game` and `Console`)?

Comment: Look into [*`List.addAll(int index, Collection<? extends E> c)`*](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/15/docs/api/java.base/java/util/AbstractList.html#addAll(int,java.util.Collection)). HTH.

Comment: I'm trying to organize the list first by games then by consoles,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use OR inside your filter to have Game and Console in the result, like this:

```
filteredListRentals = (ArrayList<Rental>) listOfRentals.stream()
    .filter(n -> n instanceof Game || n instanceof Console)
    .sorted((n1, n2) -> n1.getNameOfRenter().compareTo(n2.nameOfRenter))
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

(Remove in this case the second stream & filter assignment to filteredListRentals.)

Comment: I didn't know I could do this so that pretty cool, but it doesn't organize by games than consoles

Comment: You can also use Stream API's sorted method to sort your stream as you did in your Collections.sort method call. I updated my answer. 
(I assume your lambda expression with compareTo is as you need the sorting).

Comment: I actually just figured this out but instead, I just used the same lambda after the collection, but I really like how sorted in the stream, so ill have to try that.

Answer (score 0):

You assign the results of both streams to the same variable, so the second stream replaces the first stream.

If you want two results you need two variables. Then you can append the results of one to the other.

The logic might be something like:

```
allRentals = (ArrayList<Rental>) listOfRentals.stream().filter(n -> n instanceof Game)...
consoleRentals = (ArrayList<Rental>) listOfRentals.stream().filter(n -> n instanceof Console)...
allRentals.addAll(consoleRentals);
```

Comment: I've tried this but I can't get the list to display when I have individual variables

Comment: i actually figured out a way to make it work so thank you!

Answer (score 0):

thank you guys for your help it definitely all lead me in the right direction to figure it out

```
    fileredListRentals= (ArrayList<Rental>) listOfRentals.stream().
                    filter(n -> n instanceof Game)
                    .collect(Collectors.toList());
            Collections.sort(fileredListRentals, (n1, n2) ->
                    n1.getNameOfRenter().compareTo(n2.nameOfRenter));

    filteredConsoles = (ArrayList<Rental>) listOfRentals.stream().
                    filter(n -> n instanceof Console)
                    .collect(Collectors.toList());
            Collections.sort(filteredConsoles,(n1,n2)->
                    n1.getNameOfRenter().compareTo(n2.nameOfRenter));

            fileredListRentals.addAll(filteredConsoles);
```